# Cordova opening native browser in every link

Tags: javascript, cordova, browser, hyperlink

Im building a app in Cordova and everytime when click in an `<a href="">` it opens in native browser (safari on my iPhone).

Example,
I'm trying to open perfil.html, Cordova is opening: 
https://var/containers/Bundle/Application/51F56BF8-8BD1-44AE-8157-D9242801E4D3/HelloCordova.app/www/perfil.html
On Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to convert every link into a javascript 'location.href'.

If you have jQuery (good old friend ;) ) and you're using absolute links in anchors you can just use:

```
$(document).on("click","a[href]", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
});
```

this will set up this beavior for all of the links...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

The following code was present on the app with the objective of redirect user to the right protocol (http or ssl):

```
if (location.protocol != 'https:') {location.href = 'https:' + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);}
```

Replaced with:

```
if ( document.URL.indexOf( 'http://' ) === -1 && document.URL.indexOf( 'https://' ) === -1 ) {
    // PhoneGap application
} else {
    if (location.protocol != 'https:') {location.href = 'https:' + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);}
}
```